# Does azure graph api support user resolving?

Tags: azure, api, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am testing Azure AD graph api-users, and I'm interested about a specific capability that I couldn't find.
I want to be able to attach to the request 100 id's/userPrincipalNames  and get back an array of the user objects of these id's/userPrincipalNames(just like /users/{id} API,but for many ids), Is there an API of AZURE AD GRAPH API that can do it?

I was able to make a workaround, by using the GET /users API with query parameters(filter/search) but I didn't find it to be the best solution because the URL can't be too long(I had to put 100 ids to the search parameter).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can call `$batch` [endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching) but the limit is around 20 requests in one batch.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/users/{id1|upn1}"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/users/{id2|upn2}"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/users/{id3|upn3}"
    },
    ...
    {
      "id": "20",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/users/{id20|upn20}"
    },
  ]
}
```